# Generating QR Code to open Facebook page in iOS app

Tags: android, ios, qr-code

I'm trying to generate a QR code which should open the facebook app installed in the phone and automatically navigate to my page.

I used http://www.qr-code-generator.com to generate the QR code pointing to URL

```
fb://page/< page-id >
```

.Scanning this code works perfect on Android, but fails on iOS. I even tried

```
fb://profile/< page-id >
```

but same result on iOS.

How do I generate a QR code which works as expected on both the platform?

Comment: on iOS, url schema is fb://profile?id=8 or fb://page?id=pageid

Comment: fb://page?id=pageid works perfect on iOS.

Comment: See also [Correct way in 2018 to open Facebook app via website link?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50683354/812102)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done easily using Facebook’s internal QR Code function.

Just go to your company’s page and click on **Edit Page Info**. Scroll down a bit and you will see the QR Code.
[Facebook QR Code for a Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6DTg.png)

Click on the QR Code and it will popup in a new tab or download it. The URL in the QR Code looks something like this: https://facebook.com/qr/<QR_ID> and by scanning the code the encoded URL deep links you in the Facebook App on both IOS and Android devices or in the browser as fallback.

**Designer Facebook QR Code**

As you can see from the previous screenshot this is a simple black & white QR Code with the Facebook logo in it. To create a designer QR Code with your own colours, forms and frames you can use a designer QR Code Generator by pasting the URL of the QR Code.

[Designer QR Code Templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwHrV.png)

In the following post I wrote a more detailed description on how to create a deep linking QR Code with your own design:
https://blog.qrd.by/2021/02/19/create-facebook-qr-code-with-a-deep-link/

Comment: I am using the supplied FB QR Code as per your answer but the provided QR code does does not open the FB app for any of my followers who use an Android device.

Comment: can you provide the URL in the QR Code and the image of the QR Code?

Comment: You can visit my page https://www.facebook.com/tomsmusicbingo where I posted the QR code and asked my Android followers to try the code.  The deep link the code produces is https://www.facebook.com/qr/711066253620270 and so far my Android followers tell me it does not work.

Comment: I decided to just go with the actual web link to my page since the Deep link QR code provided by Facebook does not work for Android devices.  Hopefully Facebook will fix it.  Until then this is the best solution without having to pay a third party site to do the deep linking that Facebook can't seem to get right.  For a technology company they sure didn't the QR code thing right...

Comment: From what I can tell from the hideous maze that is Facebook, the option to generate a QR code has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

For Android the URL schema is:

```
fb://page/page_id
```

For iOS the URL schema is:

```
fb://page?id=page_id
```

So with this, I generated "Multi URL Code" at https://app.qr-code-generator.com. When the code is scanned, it first identifies the OS of the device and then executes the appropriate URL. If user scans the code in any of the other devices (other than Android and iOS), then it opens https://www.facebook.com/yourpagename in browser.

Note: page_id for your Facebook page is found under About>Page Info.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, this all works quite well automatically - just create a cool designer QR code:https://qrplanet.com/designer-qr-code-with-embeded-logo If you scan the QR code with your smartphone and have installed the Facebook app, for example, the link in the QR code is opened in the Facebook app.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33764479)