# Correct way in 2018 to open Facebook app via website link?

Tags: facebook

Let me say first that I've researched this for the past 4 hours. From various threads, I have seen that linking to `fb://page/PAGEID` is the *OLD* way of opening the Facebook app via a website link and that `fb://facewebmodal/f?href=FACEBOOKURL` is the new way.

As a reference: [Open Facebook Page in Facebook App (if installed) on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564211/open-facebook-page-in-facebook-app-if-installed-on-android/34564284)

The problem now is, I've tested both of them on iOS and Android today (June 04, 2018) and the one that works is the supposedly old way: `fb://page/PAGEID`. Did Facebook change this at some point again? I'm using the absolutely latest version of the Facebook app.

What is the correct way to do this in 2018?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out, hope it helps someone else.

If the device is Android, use:

`fb://facewebmodal/`

And if it's iOS, use:

`fb://page/PAGEID`

If you do it automatically you need to detect the device first and then redirect to the appropriate link.

Comment: The IOS form it's not working. Do we have more information on that?

Comment: For iOS you can use fb://profile?id=<numerid_id_here> (even for pages)

Comment: Does his not work anymore ? `fb://dialog/share?app_id=123&href=http://test-url.com`

Comment: both android and ios accept fb://profile/111111 in 2022. at least thats my experience on android in 2022. However if facebook is not installed on the device there is no fallback to the browser.

Answer (score 31):

Now it's changed to:

For iOS: `fb://profile/PAGEID`

For Android: `fb://page/PAGEID`

PAGEID is the numeric pageid that the page owner can see in the about box in facebook

Comment: 1000 ups.  Took me ages to find this.  Also I used https://findmyfbid.com to get the fb ids I needed.  Not sure if there is another way.

Comment: There's no numeric ID in the owner's About tab; at least, not as of 2020.

Comment: Thank you!!! Terrible why facebook is not consistent? I do not understand why iOS need "profile" and Android needs "page"? We have to add stupid hacks into code.

Comment: This worked for me in 2021 to get the page ID: https://www.facebook.com/help/1503421039731588

Comment: both android and ios accept fb://profile/111111 in 2022. at least thats my experience on android in 2022. However if facebook is not installed on the device there is no fallback to the browser.

Comment: getting the pageid was another story! I just could not find it in me page anywhere. About/More links etc.. i could not find it anywhere. i had to view page source and search for "__user" and i found it. i also tried searching for "1000" as all page id's seem to start with 1000 but there were to many results.

Answer (score 6):

Beware! I'm testing on android in September 2018:

`fb://facewebmodal/f?href=FACEBOOKURL` works, but doesn't display the page correctly - the header image is missed off and you end up in "about" with no way to like the app.

`fb://page/PAGEID` works fine in android and displays the page as intended. (for clarity this is the numeric pageid that the page owner can see in the about box in facebook)

Comment: none of these solutions opens a fb app on android in 2019

Comment: fb://page/PAGEID on my android 8 device still brings you to the page in the browser

Comment: yes, the same here. It opens fb in browser, not the fb app

Comment: Strange thing is, if your FB Url is for some events, e.g. https:/www.facebook.com/events/... so this will bring an option to open it in app or browser. But if you have just a FB page Url, it will directly open the browser.

Comment: both android and ios now accept fb://profile/111111 in 2022. at least thats my experience on android in 2022. However if facebook is not installed on the device there is no fallback to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

So I figure my solution worked best for my scenario.

By setting the target to "_top" the phone shows the pop up to choose the app that you would like to open the link on.

Comment: I'm using some AR low-code builder and it wouldn't let me put in anything that wasn't http/s so this actually was a pretty good solution for me too... thx!

Answer (score 1):

fb://profile/yournumericid
Works for iOS only

Comment: Please consider formatting your answer and add link to documentation that explain it.

Comment: Forgive me if I seem stupid, but should 'profile' be changed to the page name? e.g. fb://bbcnews/123456789 or fb://profile/123456789 ? Thanks.

Comment: @Gillian it has to be fb://profile/123456789

Comment: it seems that both iphone and android use fb://profile/1111 in 2022. at least thats what's my experience of android today.

Answer (score 1):

In 2022, the elegant ways are:

Android:

- `intent://page/PAGEID#Intent;scheme=fb;package=com.facebook.katana;end`
- `fb://page/PAGEID`

iOS:

- `fb://page/?id=PAGEID`