# <a href> link to open Facebook app to specific page

Tags: html, css, url-scheme

My question is simple, have found similar questions but none of them worked for me.

I want my a href when clickable on mobile to instantly open facebook application and redirect it to specific page.

```html
<a class="mobile" href="fb://https://www.facebook.com/fcbarcelona">mobile</a>
```

Problem is, when i click on this a href it opens facebook app but stays on news feed. Anyone experienced this and if solved it, how?

Comment: On first glance, you specify two protocols in your href: fb:// and https://. There should only be one. I'm pretty sure this will cause a problem!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to open it in Android is:

```html
<a class="mobile" href="fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://it-it.facebook.com/fcbarcelona/">mobile</a>
```

In iOS `fb://page/PAGEID` is needed instead, so you have to check in advance which operating system is running.

You can have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683354/correct-way-in-2018-to-open-facebook-app-via-website-link) for clarification.

Comment: We don't answer dupe posts, we vote/flag to close them as such.