# Create QR Code to go directly to Facebook Posting

Tags: facebook, qr-code

I know this is not the best place for this question but I am trying to create a QR code that will open the Facebook app and go to this post about a 5k we are hosting this weekend.  Any thoughts on how to do this?  I can get it to open to the post using the qr code below but not in the app.

[image]

https://www.facebook.com/hemlockcubs/posts/2133418336709704

Comment: I found this: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51034121/8411228), but it differs between Android and ios

Comment: I tried that and couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

You can use an API to generate the QrCode for you. The only thing you need to do is pass the value you want to be read.

As you didn't say which technology you're using to develop, you can search for a qrcode generator API related to your programming language or even an online one like the Google API one.

https://developers.google.com/chart/

Comment: I have been using https://www.qr-code-generator.com/ to generate what I have so far

Comment: I'm using the Google chart one, it does even have an online generator like the one you pointed.