# Open link to app instead of new page in web browser

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, footer, social-media

So I have published my website online and I tested it on my iPhone and it worked. Now when I link my facebook and linkedin page, it just opens it up in a new tab depending on what browser you are on because I am using `target="_blank"`.

What method should I use if you click on my facebook icon, it can then open to your smartphone's app if you have it installed. **Is there a way to just add in a second *alternative* within my** `a href` **tag after my** `target="_blank"`?

Here is what my link looks like currently.

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"><i id="social-fb" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
```

*Note: I replaced my link to my facebook page **#** for safety purposes.*

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Correct way in 2018 to open Facebook app via website link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683354/correct-way-in-2018-to-open-facebook-app-via-website-link/51034121) it is said to use this as your link: 
`fb://profile/PAGEID`

So your code becomes:

```
<a href="fb://profile/#"><i id="social-fb" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
```

And for Android:

```
<a href="fb://page/#"><i id="social-fb" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
```

You could probably use some fancy javascript to determine user client and redirect accordingly.