# How to convert regular Facebook Reviews url to an url that opens Reviews page in app?

Tags: facebook

Reference this topic at [Correct way in 2018 to open Facebook app via website link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683354/correct-way-in-2018-to-open-facebook-app-via-website-link)

I use fb://profile/pageID to trigger a profile page in iOS app no problem, but I can't figure out how to trigger reviews page so that I could circulate this url to customers to leave reviews.

I tried fb://profile/pageID/reviews but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?